# Rolling Back of Nested transactions

Tags: c#, transactions

I am trying to test the behavior of `Nested` Transactions in `c#`. So I created two `TransactionScope` objects. In the `outerScope`(root) I deliberately inserted duplicate `PK` value so it throws Exception AND transaction `ROLLS BACK`. But then I create a nested `TransactionScope` with `TransactionScopeOption` set to `RequiresNew` meaning it will execute separately and rolling back of outerScope will have no effect on `innerScope`. But it doesnot commit the Transactional code present inside `innerScope` becuase it doesn't reach to the next lines of code and breaks.

So my question to all of you is, how can I test Nested transaction behavior? Please advise as I have to give demo of this concept and I am totally helpless as to how am I going to explain this through code example.

Here is the code:

```
    try
    {
       using (var outerScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, option))
       {
          using (conn)
          {
             conn.Open();
             method1();
             using (var innerScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, option))
             {
               method2();
               innerScope.Complete();
             }

          }
          outerScope.Complete();
      }
    }
    catch (TransactionAbortedException tex)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(tex.Message);
    }
```